# How to consume Active Directory data from Power BI?

Tags: active-directory, powerbi, powerquery

I am using the Active Directory connector:[image]

I am consuming 2 columns:
[image]

But after hours it keeps loading and never finishes:

[image]

Any ideas on how to consume the data properly?

Answer (score 0):

you can try query maybe something like...

First thing we'll do is create our linked server, Active Directory Service Interface also known as ASDI, to Active Directory using the code below:

Make sure you change the @rmtuser and @rmtpassword variables to a login and password that has access to your Active Directory.

```
USE [master]
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ADSI', @srvproduct=N'Active Directory Service Interfaces', @provider=N'ADSDSOObject', @datasrc=N'adsdatasource'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'ADSI',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'DOMAIN\USER',@rmtpassword='*********'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'collation compatible',  @optvalue=N'false'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'lazy schema validation',  @optvalue=N'false'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'use remote collation',  @optvalue=N'true'
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Once the linked server is created we can now setup our query to return the information we need.

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery
  ( 
  ADSI,  
  'SELECT streetaddress, pager, company, title, displayName, telephoneNumber, sAMAccountName, 
  mail, mobile, facsimileTelephoneNumber, department, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, givenname 
  FROM  ''LDAP://DOMAIN.com/OU=Players,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com''
  WHERE objectClass =  ''User'' 
  ') AS tblADSI
ORDER BY displayname
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit lost.  Which connector in Power BI can I use to use this code?

Comment: @Chicago1988 [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) also you can find more info in the internet...

Comment: I dont see how this answer helps. I have tried it from SSMS (not power bi) and I have no linked server named 'ADSI'

Comment: @Chicago1988 revised...

Comment: [Querying Active Directory Data from SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/)